# position of adverbial phrase in sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice, adverbial-phrases

Using of placement of adverb, manner, place, and time in sentence. I am a bit confused speaking to place them in sentence.

While speaking with my boss:

> 1. I went to Ram's home, I connected my laptop to Ram's laptop **[ with data cable ] [ at his home yesterday ]** to send monthly report from my laptop (because my laptop was down).
> 2. I went to Ram's home, I connected my laptop to Ram's laptop **[ at his home yesterday ] [ with data cable ]** to send monthly report from my laptop (because my laptop was down).

here my concerned is to use 'with+noun' which is the best position in above sentence to use in english speaking.

Which of the two sentences is better with respect to the placement of the adverbial phrases in bold?

Answer (score 0):

It will help with overall comprehension is if you keep related topics together.

> I went to Ram's home **yesterday**, *and* I connected my laptop to Ram's laptop **with data cable** to send monthly report from my laptop (because my laptop was down).

Where and when ("home" and "yesterday) are together, as they place the activity rather than describing it. And "laptop" and "data cable" relate to each other and describe the actions taken.

Answer (score 0):

While it wasn't the quewstion asked, the example sentence:

> I went to Ram's home yesterday, and I connected my laptop to Ram's laptop with data cable to send monthly report from my laptop (because my laptop was down).

is lacking articles. it should be

> I went to Ram's home yesterday, and I connected my laptop to Ram's laptop with **a** data cable to send **the** monthly report from my laptop (because my laptop was down).